# Tables for entities with boolean fields not created

Tags: jpa, derby, glassfish-4

i tried to switch a connection pool in GlassFish 4 from MySQL to Derby. I am using Spring-Data-JPA with JPA/Hibernate. The problem is that not all tables are created with the derby pool. The tables for entities which have at least one boolean field are not created.

I found nothing in the log files. :(

My applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="project" />

    <bean
        id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property
            name="jndiName"
            value="serverPool" />
        <property
            name="lookupOnStartup"
            value="false" />
        <property
            name="proxyInterface"
            value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property
            name="generateDdl"
            value="true" />
        <property
            name="showSql"
            value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property
            name="dataSource"
            ref="dataSource" />
        <property
            name="jpaVendorAdapter"
            ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property
            name="packagesToScan"
            value="project.model.entity" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property
            name="entityManagerFactory"
            ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="project.model.repository" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Boolean was a relatively recent addition to Derby. Perhaps your copy of Derby is a bit too old, or maybe your copy of Hibernate's Derby adapter is a bit too old?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only creating boolean columns, try to use @Column to add DDL statement to the Derby database, I know this decrease portability but it will solve the problem. the property is named columnDefinition. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html

Also I think there need to be something in the log, try to increase the log level.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found the solution: I connected to the derby database and executed the command `values syscs_util.syscs_get_database_property( 'DataDictionaryVersion' );` The result was 10.1, but version 10.7 is necessary for boolean support. I then renamed the database name in the derby pool inside GlassFish (its by default `sun-appserv-samples`) and now all tables are created. With the new database the command gave me version 10.9.